# jQuery doesn't append new elements from getJSON method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Audio Home Page</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class = "content">
        <p id = "nameOfAudio"></p>
    </div>

    <p>Order will should be: Train Sound,   Emergency Sound, Horror Sound, End Of Audio Files,<br/> without old</p>

    <script>
        $(document).ready( function(){
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:8181/setCookie.php', function(data){
                "use strict";
                var items = [];
                $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                    items.push( val );
                });
                var newElem = create(items);
                $(".content").html(newElem);
            });
            function create(audioSRC) {
                output =  '<audio id="audioElement">';
                output +=  '<source src=audio/'+audioSRC[0]+' type="audio/wav" />';
                output +=  '</audio>';
                return output;
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

My problem is that I want to add a new audio element, created from a function to the `<div>`, or even `<p>`. But it doesn't work at all.

I tried from an **ajax method jquery** got no result.

JQuery methods html, append and `document.getElementById.innerHTML` don't work. I put an alert with the code returned by the function(for new elements) and there is no problem.

Is there any restriction on setting the new content in `.getJSON`, `.ajax`?

The code for setCookie is:

```
include 'getSounds.php';

$sound = getListAvailableSounds();
krsort($sound);

$audio = "";
$audioDescription = "";
$audioPosition = "";

if(!isset($_COOKIE['audio'])){
    setcookie("audio", $sound[count($sound) - 2 ]['name'], time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    setcookie("audioDescription", $sound[count($sound) - 2 ]['description'], time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    setcookie("audioPosition", (count($sound) - 1) , time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $audio =  $sound[count($sound) - 2 ]['name'];
    $audioDescription =$sound[count($sound) - 2 ]['description'];
    $audioPosition = (count($sound) - 2);
}else{
    $audio = isset($_COOKIE['audio']) ? $_COOKIE['audio'] : $audio;
    $audioDescription = isset($_COOKIE['audioDescription']) ? $_COOKIE['audioDescription'] : $audioDescription;
    $audioPosition = isset($_COOKIE['audioPosition']) ? $_COOKIE['audioPosition'] : $audioPosition;
    if($audioPosition > 0){
        setcookie("audio", $sound[($audioPosition - 1) ]['name'], time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        setcookie("audioDescription", $sound[($audioPosition - 1) ]['description'], time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        setcookie("audioPosition", ($audioPosition - 1)  , time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    } else{
        setcookie("audio", $sound[0]['name'], time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        setcookie("audioDescription", $sound[0]['description'], time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        setcookie("audioPosition", (count($sound))  , time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("audio" => $audio, "audioDescription" => $audioDescription, "audioPosition" => $audioPosition)) ;
```

And for the getSounds:

```
function getListAvailableSounds(){
    $availSounds = array();
    $audioPath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'audio' ;
    $audioExtArray = array("wav", "aiff", "mp3", "aac", "ogg", "wma");
    $flag = true;
    $jsonPath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'audio' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'files.json';
    $getfile = file_get_contents($jsonPath);
    $jsonfile = json_decode($getfile);
    if ($handle = opendir($audioPath)){
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && in_array(strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)), $audioExtArray)){
                foreach($jsonfile->records as $index => $obj){
                    if(count($obj) > 0 && $obj[0] == $file){
                        $pathParts = pathinfo($file);
                        $tempName = $pathParts['filename'];
                        if($tempName != "endofaudiofile"){
                            if($tempName >= strtotime("-48 hours"))
                                array_push($availSounds, array("name" => $obj[0], "description" => $obj[1]));
                        }else{
                            array_push($availSounds, array("name" => $obj[0], "description" => $obj[1]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $availSounds;
}
```

Comment: have you checked any browser console error? do you want to append or replace the content?

Comment: Yes. I get 200 OK for all files. The console is empty on Mozila, and Chrome

Comment: it doesnt matter append or replace. Normaly i would like a replace, but i dont know what i have done wrong

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the content you got when you are going to http://localhost:8181/setCookie.php ?

Comment: your code look good and should work as expected. Can you put alert or console.log and see what function create returns and also see what is the value of audioSRC[0]

Comment: Does the value of audioSRC[0] have a space inside it?

Comment: {…}
​
audio: "endofaudiofile.wav"
​
audioDescription: "Renamed on  WIN"
​
audioPosition: "3"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }

Comment: @MConstantin Is it your API endpoint working fine (http://localhost:8181/setCookie.php), please check With Post Man. If yes put JSON Response here also.

Comment: this is the data when i put console.log(data):Object { audio: "1535518688.wav", audioDescription: "Emergency Sound", audioPosition: "1" }

Comment: @MConstantin I noticed that this line of code not well formatted  output +=  '<source src=audio/'+audioSRC[0]+' type="audio/wav" />'; it has to be  output +=  '<source src="audio/'+audioSRC[0]+'"  type="audio/wav" />'; may it causes an issue

Comment: @Ahmed Yousif, nop. no effect. Postman request are good everytime

Comment: @MConstantin may be you have another element hast the same class  "content" check all your html elements in brawser because this call is common used

Answer (score 0):

I am a big, BIG stupid.

controls attribute was missing on audio.
Thanks for help

Comment: Don't blame yourself for doing mistakes, we all do some. Would you please edit your answer and show how you solved it? Maybe someone will have the same issue and is looking for the solution